# Grep -P (pcre) How do I compare two values? #university_exercise

Tags: regex, grep, pcre

Given this data

```
A 1.20 GBP 1.2 GBP
B 1.2 GBP 1.20 GBP
C 01 GBP 1 GBP
D 1 GBP 01 GBP
E 1.0 GBP 1 GBP
F 1 GBP 1.0 GBP
G 2.10 GBP 3.2 GBP
H 4.1 GBP 3.20 GBP
I 04 GBP 3 GBP
J 4 GBP 03 GBP
K 4.0 GBP 3 GBP
L 4 GBP 3.0 GBP
```

I have to find lines where the values are different (using grep -P).

There is one space between each number and also `3.2 = 03.20, 3.0 = 3`

I tried this

```
grep -P '([1-9][0-9]*(?:\.[0-9]*[1-9])?)(\.?0*) ([A-Z]{3}) 0*(?!\1).* \3' filename
```

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work properly. I'm not actually certain about negative lookahead.

#### Edit:

I know that there are many better ways to achieve this result.

However I'm student and it's an exercise that I have to do using grep with regular expressions.

What I have tried works until it gets more tricky tests, so if you can help, just tell me what I'm doing wrong.

The result should be:

```
G 2.10  GBP 3.2 GBP
H 4.1 GBP 3.20 GBP
I 04 GBP 3 GBP
J 4 GBP 03 GBP
K 4.0 GBP 3 GBP
L 4 GBP 3.0 GBP
```

I have tested my solution and it additionally returns:

```
A 1.20 GBP 1.2 GBP
B 1.2 GBP 1.20 GBP
D 1 GBP 01 GBP
```

I have also checked the regular expression in https://regex101.com/. And result was surprising, because for lines A and B regular expression takes only numbers after period. Check it to know what I'm saying.

**Another edit for those who tell about grep -v:**
I did not present whole exercise. There are, after every number, currencies and there is additional thing that they have to be the same, when so I use grep -v, it still doesn't work and it's known why. There has to be one negation.

Comment: You will find it simpler to use the `-v` flag on `grep` to invert the match, and then find all cases where the first field *matches* the second one, apart from any leading or trailing zeroes.

Comment: *"There are, after every number, currencies and there is additional thing that they have to be the same"* Please alter your sample data to reflect the ***real problem***.

Comment: Ah, so there's a space after the values, and the currencies are three-letter abbreviations and not single currency characters. All of that is pretty important. But what is the point of comparing the currencies in the data when they are all the same anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this bit complex regex for this task:

```
grep -P '\h+0*(?:(?:(\d+)\.?0*\h+0*\1\.?0*|(\d+\.\d*[1-9])0*\h+\g{2}0*)(*SKIP)(*F)|.*)$' file

G 2.10 3.2
H 4.1 3.20
I 04 3
J 4 03
K 4.0 3
L 4 3.0
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ut2LHt/7)

PCRE verbs `(*SKIP)(*F)` are used for skipping a match in an alternation.

---

**Alternatively**, you can use this negative lookahead regex as well:

```
grep -P '^\S+\h+(?!0*(?:(\d+)\.?0*\h+0*\1\.?0*|(\d+\.\d*[1-9])0*\h+\g{2}0*)$)' file

G 2.10 3.2
H 4.1 3.20
I 04 3
J 4 03
K 4.0 3
L 4 3.0
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/Ut2LHt/10)

---

**EDIT 2:** To include currency as well use:

```
grep -P '^\S+\h+(?!0*(?:(\d+)\.?0*\h+([A-Z]+)\h+0*\1\.?0*\h+\2|(\d+\.\d*[1-9])0*\h+([A-Z]+)\h+\g{3}0*\h+\4)$)' file

G 2.10 GBP 3.2 GBP
H 4.1 GBP 3.20 GBP
I 04 GBP 3 GBP
J 4 GBP 03 GBP
K 4.0 GBP 3 GBP
L 4 GBP 3.0 GBP
```

[RegEx Demo 3](https://regex101.com/r/Ut2LHt/11)

Comment: Can you implement to your code these currencies. They just have to be the same.

Comment: Check my answer in **EDIT 2** but I sincerely advise you not to add/edit question with new requirements now.

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple using `awk` so why bother?

```
$ awk '$2!=$4' input.txt
```

result:

```
G 2.10 GBP 3.2 GBP
H 4.1 GBP 3.20 GBP
I 04 GBP 3 GBP
J 4 GBP 03 GBP
K 4.0 GBP 3 GBP
L 4 GBP 3.0 GBP
```

`awk` automatically handles values into `float` so comparing is easy (even if float comparison is sometimes hazardous, in your case it works great)

Comment: You can also remove `{print}`

Comment: It is exercise from school and I have to use grep -P and do it with regular expressions.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I'm always too verbose when it comes to awk solutions. Excellent, thanks.

Comment: I can use only grep -P. Unfortunately grep -v is also forbidden. Can you at least tell me if using look ahead is good idea? @Jean-FrançoisFabre

Answer (score 0):

There may well be a simpler solution. This is rather ugly, but it does the job

```
grep -v -P '\s+0*(\d+(?:\.\d*[1-9])?)[.0]*\s+0*\1[.0]*\b' filename
```

Comment: @anubhava: The OP says that they tried `-v` but it doesn't work. Not that it is forbidden.

Comment: @GSxxx: You shouldn't be presenting your problem bit by bit like this. Even now it seems that we don't have a proper example of your data. Why ask a completely different question from the one you're trying to solve?

Comment: @Borodin -v does work but the task is more complex. Read the edit.

Comment: @Borodin I have presented what was needed. And also have told that I can use only grep -P not grep -vP. Now I want to explain, because people were surprised why I cannot use so obvious solution.

Comment: @GSxxx: Your questioln says that `-v` doesn't work, while your comments say that you can't use it and that it *does* work but you haven't describe the problem properly. I can't see any reason why currency symbols should stop you from using `-v`. You clearly haven't *"presented what was needed"* because you now have five answers, none of which are acceptable because of further constraints that you hadn't explained.

Comment: @Borodin Ok, so I explain why using -v is meaningless. Values have to be different and currencies the same. So when I reverse grep I have still same problem because I cannot compare currencies.

Comment: @GSxxx: Ensuring that one currency character is different from another is a whole lot easier than ensuring that two decimal values are different, while ignoring insignificant zeroes. Why don't you just present the *real* problem, together with all *real* restrictions, and leave it to us whether we want to use `-v` or anything else that you have decided is worthless?